# How to cascade delete on Entity Framework C# without editing Relationship Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my previous question I had a problem on saving a multiple models in an object at the same time.

Is there an easier way to delete the multiple models in Database?

```
public class Student
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SyTerm> SyTerm { get; set; }
}

public class SyTerm
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

A sure way to delete everything are to get all the elements and remove it one by one but is there a way that I can delete the Student object and automatically it deletes all the SyTerms and from the SyTerms it will delete all the courses associated with it?

Comment: Don't you want to set cascade delete on DB level?

Comment: As much I do not want to do that because there are instances I want to delete let say SyTerm but preserve the courses.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to configure you id properties as `Required`. EF has convention to detect your id properties and by default they are going to be required, but if you want to configure your Ids explicitly, use `Key` attribute instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete) to configure your relationships explicitly. One way is overriding the `OnModelCreating` method on your context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{


      modelBuilder.Entity<SyTerm>() 
                  .HasRequired() 
                  .WithMany(s => s.SyTerm) 
                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); 

      modelBuilder.Entity<Course>() 
                  .HasRequired() 
                  .WithMany(s => s.Courses) 
                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); 
}
```

If the relationship between two entities is required, then EF will set cascade delete by default, so in your case you could not call  `WillCascadeOnDelete` in your relationship configurations but I personally prefer do this explicitly to know what I'm doing.